# Verificar se o usuário está conectado a internet

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, conexão

Preciso saber se o usuário está conectado a internet, e se não estiver, preciso mostrar uma tela, mas o meu caso é que criei um app a partir de um site responsivo que eu tenho, no meu app não tem arquivo algum, apenas o `config.xml` apontando pro site, ao instalar o plugin, não tenho como chamar porque o app não tem nada, todos os arquivos estão no servidor, é possível instalar o plugin no servidor?

Comment: Edmilson, melhore sua pergunta, pois está pouco detalhada.

Answer (score 1):

Podes verificar a ligação através do comando [navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)

Exemplo retirado do site da MDN Web Docs

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  console.log('online');
} else {
  console.log('offline');
}
```

Outro exemplo através de event listeners que te permite manipular o estado da ligação conforme as alterações:

```
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { console.log('offline'); });

window.addEventListener('online', function(e) { console.log('online'); });
```